# Sum of function series is continuous

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Given the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^5(\frac{x}{x+2})^n$
I want to show that this sum is a continuous function in $[0,10]$.
What is the proccess I need to go through when doing so?
Do I first need to show uniform convergence?

Comment: You might as well show uniform convergence since it's so straightforward, and we know that will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the fact that a uniformly convergent series of continuous functions gives a continuous function. On the other hand, the function $g(x)=\frac{x}{x+2}$ is increasing and non-negative on $[0,10]$, hence the uniform convergence just follows from:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}n^5 \left(\frac{10}{12}\right)^{n} < +\infty. $$
The LHS can be explicitly computed (it is $3267030$), just like the original series - that is $\frac{1}{8} x (2 + x) (2 + 30 x + 75 x^2 + 60 x^3 + 15 x^4)$ - but we do not really need it to prove continuity.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you compute the original series, i.e. $$ \sum\limits^\infty_{n=1}n^5\left({x \over x+2}\right)^n = {1 \over 8}x(2+x)(2+30x+75x^2+60x^3+15x^4)\text{?}$$

Comment: @molarmass: $$\sum_{n\geq 1}n^5\left(\frac{x}{x+2}\right)^n = \left. \left(z\cdot\frac{d}{dz}\right)^5 \frac{z}{1-z}\right|_{z=\frac{x}{x+2}}.$$